# WS-Discovery Implementation for Android

Tags: android, ws-discovery

I need to use WS-Discovery on android. I googled it for almost a day but nothing found.
What would you do if you were in my situation?

Comment: Have you tried [java-ws-discovery](https://code.google.com/p/java-ws-discovery/) library or [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) framework?

Comment: I try to port java-ws-discovery to android, but its dependencies leads to failure unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm Apache CXF framework works on Android but i've spent 2 weeks fixing issues (i'd say about it as "porting to android"). But i was working on server-side and probably for client-side it's much easier.

Then use `WSDiscoveryClient` from CXF. Something about what should be done is in my [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958039/create-webservice-on-android-device-with-cxf).