# Create webservice on Android device with cxf?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, cxf

I was able to create webservice in desktop java using Apache CXF. However i need it to working on Android device.

The problem is that `java.ws` package is absent in Android. I've copied all required jar with `java.ws` classes into `libs` folder of android project , but while dexing (building of the app in IDE) i'm having the next errors:

```
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] trouble processing "javax/xml/bind/Binder.class":
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] when not building a core library.
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] going on.
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] It is also often of questionable legality.
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] building an application, then be forewarned that your application
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] system. You will be to blame for this problem.
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
Error:Android Pre Dex: [android-ws-combine.jar] 1 error; aborting
```

How can i do it? Any another way/approach to expose webservice on Android?

PS. android-ws-combine.jar was downloaded [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidwscombinejar.htm).

PPS. Actually i don't think any desktop packages like `javax.ws` are really used, except annotations. I think webservice implementation classes are in CXF completely.

Comment: the server running on your android device is not a good idea, is it really what you want?

Comment: i don't think it's not good idea. i'd like to have webservice running on Android. At the moment it's not android smartphone/tablet but embedded device running on Android.

Comment: aha ok i see it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i did it - one have to patch cxf core, cxf transport, cxf discovery api, port jaxb to android, patch txw, edit wsdls and bundle default wsdls (like ws-addressing), patch resources loading (as all META/* resources are removed by android builder), patch getting package annotations (not supported by android). 2 weeks of 10h debugging/patching and udp packets intercepting

Comment: Hello 4ntoine, can you share your solution? Have you created a new jar to distribute?